# Will this program result in a memory leak?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I have this program. I have heard that memory allocated with malloc can be freed outside of the function it was allocated in - but obviously I can't free z in main. Is there a memory leak in this program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *add(int x, int y);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int *x = NULL;
    x = add(5, 4);

    printf("%d\n", *x);
    free(x);
    return 0;
}

int *add(int x, int y) {
    int *z  =  malloc(sizeof(int));
    *z = x + y;
    return z;
}
```

Comment: No, there is no memory leak here. But you still have to check if space is really allocated and `z` is non-NULL.

Comment: Not that you can perfectly do this `z[0] = x + y;` and also declaring a pointer and calling `malloc()` in one line, can be confusing, because of the assignment operator it could look like you are dereferencing the pointer with the `*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your program would not result in a memory leak, because the memory block allocated that has been made inside the `add()` function is properly freed in the `main` function.

The only requirement for `free`ing to be valid is that the pointer passed to `free` came from `malloc`, and has not been double-`free`-d. The name of the variable to which the pointer is assigned does not matter.

The fact that the allocation and deallocation happen in different functions is not relevant as well. In fact, it is commonplace for programs with dynamic memory allocation to perform their allocations and deallocations inside different functions.

Answer (score 2):

There is not. You allocate memory for one `int`, and store that memory in the variable `x`. You then free that memory when you `free(x)`. You should, however, do a `if(z == NULL)` check in your function.

Comment: This is the best answer, because although the program will not leak memory, it could cause undefined behavior, in case the `NULL` poitner return by `malloc()` was dereferenced.

Answer (score 1):

This code will not leak.

You're correctly free-ing the allocated memory.